# ZfcBase Module on ZF2 is not getting initiated

Tags: apache, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I followed the installation instructions for ZfcUser.

composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Then I ran following commands:

```
> php composer.phar self-update
> php compsoer.phar update
```

It installed both ./zfc-base and ./zfc-user into ./vendor/zf-commons folder with paths.
In config/application.config.php I added both modules 'ZfcBase' and 'ZfcUser' to 'modules' array.

After all of that I am geting error 500. Apache error-log stays the following:

```
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/zf-commons/zfc-base/Module.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 185
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Stack trace:
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/zf2-test/public/index.php:0
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   2. Zend\\Mvc\\Application::init() /var/www/html/zf2-test/public/index.php:13
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   3. Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->loadModules() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:253
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   4. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->trigger() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:109
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   5. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   6. call_user_func() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   7. Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->onLoadModules() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   8. Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->loadModule() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:90
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   9. Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:149
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  10. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->trigger() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:171
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  11. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  12. call_user_func() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  13. Zend\\ModuleManager\\Listener\\ModuleResolverListener->__invoke() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  14. class_exists() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ModuleResolverListener.php:28
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  15. spl_autoload_call() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ModuleResolverListener.php:28
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  16. Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ModuleResolverListener.php:0
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/zf-commons/zfc-base/Module.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/bin/pear:/usr/bin/php') in /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 185
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Stack trace:
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/zf2-test/public/index.php:0
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   2. Zend\\Mvc\\Application::init() /var/www/html/zf2-test/public/index.php:13
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   3. Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->loadModules() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:253
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   4. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->trigger() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:109
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   5. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   6. call_user_func() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   7. Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->onLoadModules() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   8. Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->loadModule() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:90
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP   9. Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:149
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  10. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->trigger() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:171
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  11. Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  12. call_user_func() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  13. Zend\\ModuleManager\\Listener\\ModuleResolverListener->__invoke() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  14. class_exists() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ModuleResolverListener.php:28
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  15. spl_autoload_call() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ModuleResolverListener.php:28
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  16. Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass() /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ModuleResolverListener.php:0
[Mon Jun 03 23:52:40 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\\ModuleManager\\Exception\\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (ZfcBase) could not be initialized.' in /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:175
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(149): Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleEvent))
#1 /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(90): Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->loadModule('ZfcBase')
#2 [internal function]: Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleEvent))
#3 /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleEvent))
#4 /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners('loadModules', Object(Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleEvent), NULL)
#5 /var/www/ in /var/www/html/zf2-test/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php on line 175
```

I have set the permissions to the ./vendor folder to 0755 -R, but still, things do not work the way they should... I keep getting the same error... Without ZfcUser and ZfcBase application works fine...

Comment: This seems more like an Apache issue than a ZF one. Apache can't read your Module.php file. I'd suggest su'ing up as the Apache user to help you find out why that is.

Comment: You are right. This is an apache issue. If I try the application with php internal server `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000`, it works... But I cannot run `php -S` in production...

Comment: Stupid SElinux... I run my server on CentOS, and couple of days ago I pushed and update which included SELinux. It messed my my apache permissions. 

Configuring SElinux solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add in your application.config.php

```
        'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
        './vendor/zf-commons',
    )
```

Comment: I tried that. Technically it is not needed because the path fro zf-commons is written in composer autoload files.